# Jquery - Replace all show() and hide() with special ui effects (not hardcoded)

Tags: jquery, effects

i only use the hide() and the show() method on my website.
But some user want more effect's. Like the [jquery UI (bounce, clip, slide)](http://jqueryui.com/demos/hide/).

Is it possible to replace (not hardcoded) all hide() & show() methods with the (for example) "bounce" effect?

So that the user can decide wich effect he want?

Thanks in advance! 
Peter

Comment: To be honest, I don't think that would be a good thing regarding your UI

Comment: Are you trying to wire up these methods on some event fire in the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Method Signature for hide() looks like this

```
hide( effect, [options], [speed], [callback] )
```

So the only thing you have to do is to change the effect variable for the specific user.

i.e.
User1 `effect = bounce;`
User2 `effect = drop;`